# My PI crashes and freezes when playing music from Spotify

Tags: audio, python

I've programmed a small spotify application on my RPi that freezes quite often. I'm wondering if anyone here has any experience using pyspotify and managed to create a stable application using this library.

On another note, which might help error checking is that a hear a lot of pops from the speakers. When I use `Gstreamer` to play webradio I have no problems at all, so I'm quite sure this has to do with pyspotify or libspotify.

I've tried logging error messages to file but it seems my system freezes before it can do any such thing.

Comment: have you ran the program on a desktop?might help narrowing it down a bit.

Comment: I haven't had the time yet, I tried installing libspotify on my laptop but there are some weird dependencies that I haven't managed to solve yet.

Comment: Assuming that your code is not closed, why not post it on [Pastbin](http://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: @DanielFigueroa To get attention on your question, try migrating your question to Super User

Comment: Has this been solved? If so, please mark the answer that fixed it as such. We're trying to get this site up to par and the Q:A ratio is really bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly not an issue with library instead issue with device itself under high network load.

I had similar issue (with streaming video from internet) and limiting network throughput helped me, please, check here:

http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Crashes_occur_with_high_network_load

If this is not helping, you need to debug your code carefully to find a place where exactly in your code this problem happens.